# Humanize rails select helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following in my model:

```
  PRODUCTSTATES = %w[published coming_soon in_development cancelled]
```

I'm using that to populate a drop-down in a form, and I'm trying to use `humanize` to make the list look pretty, but can't seem to get it.

```
  <%= f.select :status, Product::PRODUCTSTATES %>
```

`Product::PRODUCTSTATES.humanize` obviously doesn't work, nor does converting to a string before hand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass an array like

```
[['caption1', 'value1'], ['caption2', 'value2']]
```

to `select` helper and it'll generate smth like

```
<select>
  <option value="value1">caption1</option>
  <option value="value2">caption2</option>
</select>
```

In your case you can do like that:

```
<%= f.select :status, Product::PRODUCTSTATES.map { |s| [s.humanize, s] } %>
```

You'll get humanized versions of the statuses displayed on the page and the original  (non-humanized) versions will be sent to the server when the form is submitted.

See [`select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) and [`options_for_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) docs for more information.

Comment: thanks, <%= f.input :status, collection: Product::PRODUCTSTATES.map { |s| [s.humanize, s] } %> 
for simple_form_for in case if sbdy'll need it